# React JS to display month based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, frontend

I am trying to display the month name based on user input. I have file named Constants js file in that I have defined my month array.
    case 1:
    when user enters 4 in the text field on clicking submit button it should display April month
    case 2:
    when user enter 33 month number it should display 'invalid month number'

```
Home JS file
<code>
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import constants from './Constants';

class Home extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
        value : ''
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick = (event) => 
    {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value})
    }

  render()
  {
    let newvalue = this.value;
     let latestvalue = constants.MONTHS[newvalue] == null ? 'invalid month' : constants.MONTHS[newvalue]  ; 
    return(
        <div className='home'>
        <h1>Welcome to my portfolio website</h1>
        Enter Month number <input type="text" value={this.state.value}/> 
        <button type="button" onSubmit={this.handleClick()}> </button>
        <p> Feel free to browse around and learn more about me.</p>
        Month is {latestvalue}
      </div>

     );
  }

}

export default Home;
</code>

Constants JS file

<code>

const constants = {

        MONTHS: ['','Jan','Feb','Mar','April','May','June','July']

}

export default constants;
</code>

It should display month or invalid month
```

I am getting  this error " TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"

Comment: I think your error is on 
`constants.MONTHS[newvalue] == null`, as an "un-findable" index of an array will returns `undefined`

Comment: you can one-shot it with `let latestvalue = constants.MONTHS[newvalue] || 'invalid month'`

Comment: I am getting this error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Comment: Remove the parenthesis
`onSubmit={this.handleClick}` . You are calling the handleClick method, instead of  attaching it.

Comment: Thanks now error doesnt show but I am not able to enter anything in the input field

Comment: Ok, remove the onClick event on the button, and add a `onChange={this.handleClick}` on the input. Maybe change `handleClick` to `handleChange` for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import constants from './Constants';

class Home extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
        value : 0,
        month: constants.MONTHS[0]
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick = (event) => 
    {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value})
    }
    handleSubmit = () => {
        const month = constants.MONTHS[this.state.value] || 'invalid month'
        this.setState({
        month: month
       })
    }

  render()
  {

    return(
        <div className='home'>
        <h1>Welcome to my portfolio website</h1>
        Enter Month number <input type="text" onChange={this.handleClick} value={this.state.value}/> 
        <button type="button" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> </button>
        <p> Feel free to browse around and learn more about me.</p>
        Month is {this.state.month}
      </div>

     );
  }

}

export default Home;
```

Comment: This is working fine but problem is when I enter in the input field dynamically it is handing and displaying I want it to display month only when I click on submit button